# Replace SSL Certificate on Amazon EC2

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, openssl, ssl-certificate

I've got 2 .CRT files one called: "gd_bundle" other called something like "48f...". both are .CRT files.

How can I use this files to upload a new certificate to my amazon ec2 instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the high level steps:

1. You must have a private key file
2. and a certificate file
3. copy the certificates and key in some location like `/etc/ssl/certs` and `/etc/ssl/private` respectively
4. Which web server are you using? You need to configure your web server to listen on port 443
5. you also need to configure your web server to use this certificate and the private key for SSL encryption/decryption

Here are the SSL configuration step for [apache](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm) and [nginx](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-nginx.htm)